# rake-pipeline Assetfile: How to take vendor javascript from gems?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, rake-pipeline

Is it possible to take vendor javascripts from gems for rake-pipeline? Gems like `handlebars-source`, `ember-source` or `jquery-rails`. 
Similar to what Rails does, I guess.

Is it a good idea to let `gem` keep vendor javascripts up to date?